# Recovery of deleted data on SSD / USB Flash

Tags: usb, ssd, file-recovery

Is there a way to recover deleted data from a SSD / USB Flash drive?

All I could find were recovery for damaged drives, but I want to recover deleted data.

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for Recuva.

http://www.piriform.com/recuva

(Same people as CCleaner and some other neat tools.) Completely free.

The fact that it's an SSD/USB drive shouldn't make much of a difference. If it is an SSD with Trim support, connected to the motherboard SATA port, and you're on Win7, then you may be in a bit of trouble.

Comment: But Win7 also has the built-in Shadow Copy service - therefore deleted file are not immediately "TRIMMed". Additionally TRIMMed means that the blocks are marked free but it may depend on the SSD if free blocks are always empty or if they contain the old data until the block has been reused.

Comment: This does not help for SSD. Windows 7 64 but using SSD on SATA on a motherboard - files are completely removed it seems.

Comment: Free, but the site tries to steer you toward a "professional" version with a feature list that could be interpreted as saying the free version cannot recover files: http://www.piriform.com/recuva/download.  I suspect that any even slightly sophisticated user will realize that the feature list is misleading, but that many people will be deceived into thinking only the paid version will meet their needs.  And when you're in a panic over lost files you're less likely to be thinking straight, and more ready pony up the cash.

Comment: @martona I have windows 10 with trim enabled and I am using SSD with TRIM too. Why even after deleting files from recyble bin the RECUVA can still recover files?

Answer (score 5):

When a file gets deleted, it's reference from the file table of the storage is simply removed. The data itself doesn't get changed unless you run a program that specifically does this kind of "deletion." This means that the data still exists, but is more or less "hidden," so you'll want to use some external program.

I've always found [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)/[Photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) (They are two different programs, but they are made by the same people and Photorec is just basically a specific portion of Testdisk) to be absolutely amazing for file recovery, and they are both free to use programs.

Comment: Unless the downvoter would like to state their reason, I don't really see anything wrong with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Recover My Files](http://www.recovermyfiles.com/) which is pretty awesome and helped me many times with recovering my documents.