# Software to recovery data from

Tags: formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recovery of deleted data on SSD / USB Flash](https://superuser.com/questions/223718/recovery-of-deleted-data-on-ssd-usb-flash)

Anyone know of a good software to recovery files off of a formatted memory stick? I did some searching and found a demo, .. anyone know of a free one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how the memory stick was formatted. If it was written with zeros, the chances are slim to none.

I don't know of any utilities devised specifically for memory sticks, but it's worth giving [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com) a look.